# Jquery Ajax beforeSubmit

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I am trying to use Ajax Form Submit. In the BeforeSubmit function. i want to get the id of the form thats being submited.

```
function StatusComments() {

    $('.status-comment').submit(function() {
        $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
        return false;
    });

    //$('.status-comment').ajaxForm(options);


    var options = {
        beforeSubmit: showRequest,
        success: showResponse,
        resetForm: true
    };

    function showRequest(formData, jqForm, options) {
        var formID = $(this).attr("id");
        alert(formID);
        $('.comment'+formID).attr('disabled', true);

    }

    function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, form) {
        var formID = form.attr('id');
        $("#commentbox-"+formID).before(responseText);
    }

}
```

but i get formID as undefined in showRequest :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The documentation for the plug-in](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#options-object) says that the form instance will be in your `jqForm` argument (and already be a jQuery instance), not `this`. So:

```
function showRequest(formData, jqForm, options) {
    var formID = jqForm.attr("id"); // <== Change on this line
    alert(formID);
    $('.comment'+formID).attr('disabled', true);
}
```

This is not how jQuery-style callbacks normally work, hence your confusion, but that's what the docs say.

Comment: Crowder: thanks. can you point out what mistake i have been doing with the callbacks ?

Comment: @Harsha: *"can you point out what mistake i have been doing with the callbacks?"* Sorry, when I said *"This is not how jQuery-style callback normally work"* I meant that the **author** of the plug-in was doing things in a slightly unusual way, not you. Normally, with jQuery, in callbacks `this` points to the relevant DOM element and so I would have assumed, like you did, that `this` was the form element. But this plug-in does it differently and passes you the reference to the form as the second argument to the callback. But they provide decent docs, so... :-)